# Add a char to the start of each line in JavaScript using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I use the `replace` function to add a single character to each line in JavaScript using a regular expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the *beginning of line* regex:

```
// X is the single char to add:
str = str.replace(/^/gm, "X");
```

The `gm` flags cause a match across lines.

Comment: That's some nice use of the multiline matching.